# How to save and load a .blend file from a alpha version?

Tags: interface

I was working with blender version 3.0 and was using geometry nodes that aren't available in previous version. I can save it, but when I load it again it opens in blender 2.93, and the nodes that aren't in this version turn red and change their names to "undefined". I was trying to right click on the file, choose "open with" (or whatever it's called in English) and select blender 3.0, but it still opened in 2.93

Comment: Your OS has associated the ".blend" file type with version 2.93.  If you want to open a file with 3.0 alpha you need to find the 3.0 alpha binary on your disk, run it, and then use the open menu entry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use drag & drop to open the file with a specific Blender version if you have mupltiple versions on your PC:

- start the Blender version that you want to use.
- open the file manager/explorer and drag & drop the blend file that you want to open into the started Blender
- confirm the little dialog that appears in Blender with "Open".